# Accessing nested Model from javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My class and view model ,

```
public class MyClass {
[Key] public int Id {get;set;}
public name {get;set;} ....etc.
}
```

and

```
public class MajorViewModel {
[key] public string id{get;set;}
public List<MyClass> myClass {get;set;}
...etc;
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult viewDetail() {
 MajorVeiwModel mv = new MajorViewModel()
 ...
 ..
  return View(mv);
}
```

Child partial View

```
@model namespace.MyClass
<div> @html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.id) 
<div> @html.DisplayFor(model=>model.id) 
  ....and tens of other properties..
```

In View, I have

```
@model namespace.MajorViewModel 
<div> @html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.id) 
      @html.DisplayFor(model=>model.id) </div>
@for(var I=0; I< Model.myClass.count(); i++)
{
 <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.myClass[i].id)
 <a href="#" id="displayId" data-bind: @Model.myClass[i])  <==not sure how to pass data
}

<script>
  $("#displayId").click(function(){
      alert(this.name);     <== how to access MyClass[i].name for respective row for which it was clicked.
  var resultDiv = $('<div id="childView"></div>');
  var htmlContext = $(this).parent();
  //somehow get the model selected and create html for child
  var result = ???   <== fill it with child partial view html
  //TODO ...FILL THE result
  resultDiv.html(result);
  alert(resultDiv);
});
</script>
```

In the code above I am trying to bind/link data for each row but not sure how to bind, so that on link click, in JavaScript I can access the all the data(tens of properties like MyClass[i].name etc) of i'th instance clicked by user and display.
 Do I need to serialize data but how to link it for each row? There is not table. to use @Html.HiddenFor.

Comment: Add the property values as `data-` attributes - e.g. `<a .... data.name="@Model[i].name" data-xx="@Model[i].xx .....` and access the values using `var name = $(this).data('name');` etc

Comment: @Stephen, I would like to pass the whole model of type myClass that is  @Model.myClass[i] , so that it strongly typed with the View created for myClass say in popup dialog window.  Please note that I commented that there are "tens of properties like MyClass[i].name etc) ".

Comment: You need to add each individual property - you cannot add the 'model' to a `data-` attribute. The alternative is to just use relative selectors to get the text associated with your `DisplayFor()` methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks , you are bit closer to my main query. "use relative selectors to get the text associated with your " that is how to pass variables and convert variables to model from one view to another view which is expecting a model of @ model namespace.MyClass type. As MajorViewModel view contain the child model data, should it require server roundtrip to display myClass data in a separate view? How to accomplish this child view to display.

Comment: Its not clear what your wanting to do in the script. Do you have a modal popup form that you want to populate with the values from a 'row'? But you last comment seems to suggest you want to redirect to a different view, it which case just use `@Html.ActionLink()` and pass the `id` property only and then get the data model in the controller method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I updated the question to get more clarity for the task I am trying to achieve. Yes, looks you got the right nerve. The popup is a view actually and I am trying to avoid server trip as all the data is already there in view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142812/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-aks).

Answer (score 0):

instead of the "for" statement use the "foreach" statement.

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.myClass)
{
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.id)
 <a href="#" id="displayId" data-name="item.name" class="clickfunction" )>item.Name </a>
}

<script>
  $(".clickfunction").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data("name")
      alert(name);     
});
</script>
```